# Making a div appear as a triangle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a triangular div. Well, actually I've created the div making use of the border trick. The issue I'm having is there is a transparent line running in the middle of the triangle. It's like a perpendicular line dividing the right angle into two equal triangles. I've tried everything to make the transparent line opaque div but it's not working. Here's my code. Thanks in advance for helping me fix this bug.
CSS

```
.shopitemz .col-md-3 .card .brand {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 70px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12%;
  top: -3%;
}

.brand.r {
  border-color: transparent transparent #CC0000 transparent !important;
}
```

and HTML,

```
<div class="row shopitemz">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="branded">Giovencci</div>
      <img src="Images/product_images/product2.png"
        style="width:90%;height:auto;text-align:center;margin:3% 5%" />
      <hr />
      <div class="text-center">
        <p>Natasha Bedonna Eye shadow Pallette</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p style="color:black">&#8358;2500</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any perpendicular line, looks pretty clean to me (Chrome)

Comment: I'm using mozilla firefox developer's edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

```css
.shopitemz .col-md-3 .card .brand {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 70px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12%;
  top: -3%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.brand.r {
  border-color: transparent transparent #CC0000 transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row shopitemz">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="branded">Giovencci</div>
      <img src="Images/product_images/product2.png" style="width:90%;height:auto;text-align:center;margin:3% 5%" />
      <hr />
      <div class="text-center">
        <p>Natasha Bedonna Eye shadow Pallette</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p style="color:black">&#8358;2500</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```